# Simple Entity Framework Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm getting a strange error I can't work out for a very simple example.

The model is simple User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

the dbcontext is Database.cs

```
public class DataBase : DbContext
{
    public DataBase() : base("name=DefaultConnection") {}

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and the code

```
DataBase db = new DataBase();

public ActionResult About()
{
    var u = new User() { Name = "Mickey Mouse", Email = "mickey@mouse.com" };
    db.Users.Add(u);
    db.SaveChanges();
    var model = db.Users.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

gets error

Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'.

Comment: Are you using the "code first" approuch? If so, you should be overriding `onModelCreating` on the `DbContext` and setting a db initializer.

Comment: Yes I am, can you provide an example. The examples I'm following don't have this.

Comment: Take a look at this if you are still interested in database initializers: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is nothing wrong with the code, the db was weird, I deleted it and let it generate again and all was good.

Probably something to do with me originally having

```
public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

in my dbcontext, still getting my head around the singular vs plural stuff